# Reference a variable out side the component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This might seem like a silly question, but I am curious if this is possible (recommended). Consider the following:

```
export default class Example extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this._variable = value;
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>{this.props.children}</div>);
  }
}
```

Now I know I can pass `this._variable` down to the children such that:

```
this._childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
    (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
        variable:   this._variable,
    })
);
```

Now ever child has access to `this.props.variable`. But (and I dont understand fully this concept) could I use context or something simmilar to be able to:

```
// In another component some where ... 
render() {
  // reference variable (this._variable, or variable) here

  <Example>
    // Children here ...
  </Example>
}
```

is this what context is used for? Or am I doing something horribly wrong? essentially I **want to reference this._variable out side the element but set it up inside the element**. Is that possible?

Comment: `redux` could help you I think.

Comment: I am looking to do this with out third party libraries. If possible. @SteevePitis

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use context to pass a variable to all descendants of a component, but as a general rule of thumb you should **avoid using context if you do not absolutely need it**. Context breaks the data flow pattern of React and generally makes the code harder to read as props might be implicit instead of explicit. According to the docs:

> Using context will make your code harder to understand because it makes the data flow less clear. It is similar to using global variables to pass state through your application.

Generally context works best for things like theme information and it is also useful in certain routing libraries. Usually there is a better way to pass down data (your `cloneElement` on `React.Children` example is perfectly fine and a fairly common piece of code that you'll find in a lot of React projects).

If you still want to use context after that warning, then you'll need to make some adjustments to the component that *provides* the context (usually a wrapper) and the component(s) that *receives* the context.

Your context provider needs a `getChildContext` function that returns the context object you want to make available to all of its children. You will also need to declare what the `childContextTypes` are as a property of the class.

```
class Example extends Component {

  getChildContext() {
    return { variable: 'foo' };
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>{this.props.children}</div>);
  }
}

Example.childContextTypes = {
  variable: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

Then wherever you define the components that will be passed as children that you want to *receive* the context, you will need to add the same `childContextTypes` property. It will have access to the context through the `this.context` object.

```
class Child extends Component {

  render() {
    return (<div>{this.context.variable}</div>);
  }
}

Child.childContextTypes = {
  variable: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

Writing the `childContextTypes` is **necessary**. As you can see, using context doesn't always mean less code.